# Detect and add spaces when the text breaks line in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I need to display a text and if it goes to the next line (because the text is long), then I want to add some spaces at the start. how can I do it?

what I want to do.

```
# when text is small

comment : he is a good person

# when text is long

comment : he is a good person and
          funny.
```

I am using a `<Text>` tag and tried to use

```
onLayout={(event) => {
      var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
```

but couldn't figure out how to add space at the beginning of the second line.

BTW I have made sure that it does go to next line once the text fits the view so all I need to know is how to detect it and add some spaces.

Edit:

Let me add some of my currrent code

```
const content =() => {
    return(
      contents.map((i, key) => `${i} ${key+1 == contents.length? '' : '/'} `) 
    )
  }

return(
    <View  onLayout={(event) => {
      var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
      dispatch(setHeight({height: height}));
      } }
    >
      <Text > 内容： {content()} </Text>
    </View>
```

I had made it break line based on the no of contents(hard coded). but it causes problem based on the length of content

```
const content =() => {
    return(
      contents.map((i, key) => `${i} ${key+1 == contents? '' : '/'} ${(key+1)%5 == 0 && key+1 != contents.length? "\n                  " : ''}`) 
    )
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: it seems this is something to do with native iOS and Android Label due to its high customizablity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do so complicated, just use CSS to achieve:

Something like this:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>  //change children direction to "row" and let it parallel
    <Text>123:</Text>
    <Text numberOfLines={10}>  // ← update  something like this!!!
      This is a lot of word... This is a lot of word... This is a lot of
      word... This is a lot of word... This is a lot of word... This is a
      lot of word... This is a lot of word... This is a lot of word...
      This is a lot of word... This is a lot of word... This is a lot of
      word... This is a lot of word...
    </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

[image]

You could try to change the first text's backgroundColor will be more easier to understand how's it work.

[Code on sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-matsumoto-5tb05?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try this method before. but it causes 2 problems

Comment: what problem? could you paste the error or problem, maybe could fix?

Comment: Sorry I was editing it and pressed the wrong button. My Bad. The problem is 1. The line doesn't break anymore at the end of the screen. 2. The onLayout is called multiple times and the height keeps increasing. (I have added the code to the question )

Comment: 1. I think you just add like `<Text numberOfLines={10}>{bodyText}</Text>` would be fixed.
2.If you use my solution, you don't have to change the height by yourself?

Comment: If you really want a parameter like that, you could change the numberOfLines value to parameter. But I assumed don't have to.

Comment: thanks for the first one. in the second what I am doing is setting the layout height here and using it somewhere else. so I am not changing it, I am storing it to be used later

Comment: Maybe setting up a variable if the onLayout event is already fired or not and checking it before running the function, and isn't it trigger multiple times using your original method?

Comment: yes. that works. Thanks. it doesn't look like the best way, but it works. So Thanks again.

Comment: yeah, I guess it have better solution, but we could let it work first, and improve in the future lol.

Comment: And I have to remind you, if your word will more then 10 lines, you should set the numberOfLines more then your word line, or it may fixed on 10 lines.